# Excel Sum Formula With Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, sum, sumproduct

So I'm having a problem with summing some data in a range with multiple criteria. Take the data below as an example:
[image]

I would like to sum all numbers where: Name = Bob AND the top row is equal to 02/01/20.

The current formula i have is with a SUMPRODUCT, but i'm not sure if it's the solution

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Names="Bob")*(Dates="02/01/2020")*Values)
```

Where Names is a named range for my names, Dates is a named range for my dates and Values is a named range for all my values in the table. However, the formula keeps resulting in "#VALUE!".

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Dates in Excel are numbers, the rest is just formatting so either reference a cell containing the date or use a formula such as DATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn your date string into a date value.  So try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Names= "Bob")*(Dates=--"02/01/2020")*Values)
```